# Understanding an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let

$$R = \{ \left\langle {x,y} \right\rangle  \in \wp (\mathbb{Z}) \times \wp (\mathbb{Z})|\exists t \in \mathbb{Z}.y = x + t\} $$

This is the equivalence class for $\{0\}$ 
$$\begin{array}{l}
 {[\{ 0\} ]_R} = \{ A \in \wp (\mathbb{Z})|\exists t \in \mathbb{Z}.A = \{ 0\}  + t\}  \\ 
  = \{ A \in \wp (Z)|\exists t \in \mathbb{Z}.A = \{ t\} \}  \\ 
  = \{ \{ t\} |t \in \mathbb{Z}\}  \\ 
 \end{array}$$

I'm not sure I understand the equivalence class here. Why is it a singelton, $\{0\}$ and not $0$? Also, I don't think I understand the role of $A$ correctly in this definition.

Comment: What that $\;\wp(\Bbb Z)\;$ thing? The power set of the integers?

Comment: @DonAntonio, Indeed. Isn't it the right notation?

Comment: Yes, it is. And that is your question about.

Comment: Well, that "p" is used for other things (say, Weierstrass function in elliptic curves), but it's fine...but then $\;x,y\subset\Bbb Z\;$ , so I'm not sure what does $\;y=x+t\;$ **for sets** means...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $\wp(\Bbb Z)$ means the **powerset** of $\Bbb Z$, i.e. the set of all *subsets* of $\Bbb Z$.

In particular, $A\in\wp(\Bbb Z)$ means $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$, and that's how $\{0\}$ fits in the picture.

For a subset $x\in\wp(\Bbb Z)$, we *define*
$$ x+t :=\{a+t\in\Bbb Z\,\mid\,a\in x\}\,,$$
i.e. the relation $R$ in words would say that $xRy$ means that subset $x$ can be *shifted* to subset $y$, e.g. we have $\{0,3,9\}\,R\,\{-5,-2,4\}$, and, of course, $\{0\}\,R\,\{t\}$ for any $t\in\Bbb Z$...

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, Berci re-wrote, explained and answered other person's question. I can't guess that much...